# Compare a string to all elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I know there is probably a way to do this but the majority of the ways to do this were the opposite way of what i am trying to accomplish. I want to compare elements in an array (English dictionary words from "words" program), and see if they are contained anywhere in a string. for example if i type in 123hello456, it will scan my string against the array and find hello within that string even tho it is surrounded by numbers.

```
read -p "enter test string: " string
array=(`cat /usr/share/dict/words`)
if [[ "${array[*]}" == *"$string"* ]]; then
echo "there is a dictionary word in your string"
else
echo "no dictionary words contained within your string"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` and `grep`:

```
if printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -qFx -- "$string"; then
  : match found
fi
```

- `-F` matches the content as strings, not patterns
- `-x` matches the whole line to prevent false positives arising out of partial matches
- `-q` suppresses output
- `--` prevents issues caused by a leading `-` in `$string`

Answer (score -1):

One simple option would be to use `grep`, which allows you to specify multiple patterns to match, and also to use fixed strings (rather than regular expressions) to avoid that overhead.

```
$ grep -F -f /usr/share/dict/words <<<'123hello456'
123hello456
```

This actually matches "ello" since that comes earlier in my `words` file, but it'd match "hello" too.

You can use the `-q` flag to suppress `grep`'s output, so your script would become:

```
read -p "enter test string: " string
if grep -q -F -f /usr/share/dict/words <<<"$string"; then
  echo "there is a dictionary word in your string"
else
  echo "no dictionary words contained within your string"
fi
```

Note this isn't terribly efficient if you're calling this often, since `grep` has to re-load the whole `words` file every time. Depending on what else you're trying to accomplish I'd definitely consider swapping to a "real" language such as Python for a task like this.